# How can i display a taxonomy? i have created a plugin and then a custom type. and a taxonomy , also i have register it

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, customization, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

So my question is where i can place the code to display the taxonomy? i found this code

```
`function get_taxonomies( $args = array(), $output = 'names', $operator = 'and' ) {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
 
    $field = ( 'names' === $output ) ? 'name' : false;
 
    return wp_filter_object_list( $wp_taxonomies, $args, $operator, $field );
}`
```

but it dont work and i get errors. i mean i have to make a new file place it there?

the taxonomy is

```
   function create_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Offer'),
        'singular_name' => __('offer'),
        'add_new' => __('New offer'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New offer'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit offer'),
        'new_item' => __('New offer'),
        'view_item' => __('View offer'),
        'search_items' => __('Search offer'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No offer Found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No offer found in Trash'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'custom-fields',
            'thumbnail',
            'page-atributes'
        ),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
    );
    register_post_type('offer', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'create_post_type');


function htl_register_taxonomy()
{
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('hotel'),
            'singular_name' => __('hotel'),

        ),
        'public' => true,
    );

    register_taxonomy('hotel', array('offer'), $args);
}
add_action('init', 'htl_register_taxonomy');
```

Comment: Do you mean the archive URLs for listing posts in that taxonomy or CPT? I'm not sure what you are trying to display, do you mean taxonomy _terms_? Be as specific as you can and give examples

Comment: im trying to display the hotel tags in the photo https://ibb.co/thBkRfH

Comment: Ah so you want to list terms in a taxonomy

Comment: yes and diplay this list

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in your theme custom page or debugging page:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'offer',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 //show all posts
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);


if($loop->have_posts()){
    while($loop->have_posts()){
        $loop->the_post();

    $id = get_the_ID();

    $tax = get_the_terms($id, 'hotel');

    print_r($tax);

    }//endwhile
    wp_reset_postdata();
}//endif
```

Comment: Note that `wp_reset_query` should only be used to clean up after `query_posts` calls, use `wp_reset_postdata` instead

Comment: thanks for correcting

Comment: sorry for being irrelevant, but where it the custom page? i created a plugin and inside  the php file, i have to create another file and place the code?  https://ibb.co/nkwPT6j

Comment: i often create **custom page template** inside active theme, for example **template-test.php**

and the code just like this:

`<?php
/*
Template Name: TEST CODE
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

// put your code want to debug


<?php get_footer(); ?>`

and create new page and use **TEST CODE** page attribute. after being ok, you can put the code in your plugin. then run with filter or hook that you want

Comment: still i dont understand it!! i found this code but it display the categories not the hotel , can i changed it to show the hotel?

Comment: try this one bro https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/